# Flutter : How to set container size to wrap_content in Wrap widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to set `Container` size to wrap_content instead of it taking the whole screen width. I can get the wrap_content size by changing `Wrap` widget with `Row`, but it will overflow if the children widget is bigger than the screen.

Below is the code I use with `Wrap` widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text('Container 1'),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          color: Colors.cyan,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Container 2'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I get this result with `Wrap` widget

[image: With Wrap widget]

When I change it to `Row` instead of `Wrap`, I get this result
[image: With Row widget]

How can I achieve this using `Wrap` widget? Or is there any other widget similar to `Wrap` where the overflowed widget will automatically build into a new line?

Comment: Just set the `direction` parameter of `Wrap` to `Axis.vertical`.

Comment: I want the `direction` to be horizontal (similar behavior to `Row` widget) @Enzo

Comment: @SieIvanSiehoyono Do you `absolutely` need to use `Container`, you can just apply `backgroundColor` to `Text` widgets;

Comment: @NisanthReddy Yes, I need to put it in `Container` since I want to set it to a certain height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use the `Column` widget as your `Text` parent.
Then give `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` to center your `Text`.

```
Container(
  height: 100.0,
  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text('Container 1'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Wrap the containers with an `UnconstrainedBox` widget, this way the container will be free to size itself to its children’s size.

Comment: I've been for hours trying many many many proposals from a number of answers from different questions regarding this problem, and only this solution (which is very simple, btw) worked out for me! Cheers! Thank you so much @Luwx!